# Bash - Wrapping another command's parameters

Tags: bash, shell, parameters

Wrapping another command's parameters

I have a command `tool1` that parses arguments this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# ...
while [[ $# -ge 1 ]]
do
        key="$1"
        case $key in
                -o|--option)
                OPT="$2"
                shift
                ;;  

                -u|--user)
                USR="$2"
                shift
                ;; 

                -*) 
                echo -e "Unrecognized option: \"$key\"" && exit 1 
                ;;  

                *)  
                OTHERS+=("$1")
                ;;  
        esac
        shift
done
# ...
```

I have `tool2` that calls `tool1`. Thus `tool2` will have to pass parameters to `tool1`. It may also need to process the same parameters (`--user`)

`tool2` looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# ...
while [[ $# -ge 1 ]]
do
        key="$1"
        case $key in
                -O|--option2)
                opt2="$2"
                shift
                ;;  

                -u|--user)
                USR="$2"
                OTHERS+=("-u $2")
                shift
                ;;  

                -*) 
                echo -e "Unrecognized option: \"$key\"" && exit 1 
                ;;  
                *)  
                OTHERS+=("$1")
                ;;  
        esac
        shift
done

## Call tool1 with other parameters to pass
bash tool1.sh ${OTHERS[@]}
# ...
```

To sum up
`--option2` is an option used only by `tool2`.
`--user` is common to both tools, and may be used by `tool2` too, before calling `tool1.sh`. Because of this, in this example `--user` has to be explicitly passed to `tool1` thanks to the array `OTHERS`.

I'd like to know about possible and/or alternative ways of dealing with such parameter redundancies. A methodology that would help me wrapping another tool's expected parameters/options, without having to copy/paste the lines regarding the parsing of such redundant parameters/options.

Comment: Why don't you use `getopt` builtin ?

Comment: For portability issues. `getopt` isn't standardized. `getopts` however doesn't support long options.

Comment: What if an option is in the second script but not the first? Also if both scripts can act upon a parameter how is it redundant?

Comment: It's worth [edit]ing your question to clarify if tool1 is a stand-alone command that is also called outside of tool2. If tool1 is only called by tool2, I'd write it as a function within tool2.

Comment: @123 the parsing is redundant. My question is more a whim to do something elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tool2`'s approach is fine. However, you aren't setting `OTHERS` correctly.

```
-u|--user)
  USR="$2"
  OTHERS+=("-u" "$2")
  shift
```

`-u` and its argument need to remain separate array elements, just as they were separate arguments to `tool2`. You also need to quote the expansion of `OTHERS`, to preserve arguments containing word-splitting characters or globs:

```
bash tool1.sh "${OTHERS[@]}"
```

Finally, all-uppercase variable names are reserved for use by the shell itself; don't define such names yourself. Just use `others` instead of `OTHERS`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Capitalizing names for exported variables is ok though, right?

Comment: If by "capitalize", you mean `Others`, sure. Don't create any variables consisting solely of uppercase letters yourself, though. Whether or not you are exporting the variable is irrelevant.

Comment: OK cause in some official documentation I did read that declaring personal uppercase variable (OTHER) is relevant only if the said variables are exported.